# Is Cmm suitable for use in compilers besides GHC?

Tags: compilers, intermediate-representation

Cmm is a fork of C-- used by GHC for codegen. I was previously thinking of using LLVM but Cmm seems to be a nicer, easier way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what your goals are.
Having looked into GHC's backend a fair bit, while Cmm is certainly a usable backend, using it will almost certainly create a permanent dependency on the entire GHC library. Cmm these days is quite tied into the GHC source code, and therefore separating it from the the GHC source would be quite difficult - If you're OK having a dependency on GHC, then sure, it's most likely completely doable to use Cmm as a backend.

I will note that having a dependency on LLVM is probably "less extreme" then having a dependency on GHC, as LLVM has been ported to more platforms then GHC and is almost certainly installed more often.

In terms of Cmm being "easier", I can't comment, as I've used neither for a large project.